# Firefox rendering font differently than other browsers - fixable with feature detection?

Tags: firefox, browser-detection

I understand and agree with the shift from browser detection to feature detection but it won't help me with this problem: I'm using the Dosis font, whose letters are displayed farther apart by Firefox than by other browsers. Currently, I'm using `navigator.userAgent` to detect the browser and adjust letter-spacing accordingly. Now, what Firefox feature could help me make this detection?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that comes to mind is that, if the spaced-out letters result in overall longer text strings than normal, create an invisible `<div>` somewhere with Dosis text and check its width. This would check for the specific error, not just the browser.

Comment: Yes, but there's no error here; FF just renders text differently. I'm about to try FitText, a plugin I just bumped into. If I get a positive result, I'll post a comment. Thanks for your answer.